# Unable to add data to html table in correct position

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I am trying to insert data from a JSON object into a table that I receive back from my rest controller. I am using a vue-for to populate the names in my table on page load but when I want to add to the table after it doesn't seem to add data in the correct place. Is this because of the vue-for I am using ?

Here is my file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:v-on="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="mainStyles.css">

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
<div id="page-container">
    <div id="content-wrap">

        <div th:replace="fragments/header :: header"></div>
        <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div th:replace="fragments/adminPageTitle :: adminPageTitle ('Weekly Roster')"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 generate-schedule-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="postToSolver()">Generate Roster</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 generate-schedule-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-success" v-on:click="insertSolvedDataToTable()">Populate Schedule</button>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br><br>

        <div class="container" id="main">
            <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee</th>
                    <th v-for="day in daysOfWeek">{{ day }}</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="schedule-body">
                <tr id="schedule-body-row" v-for="employee in employees">
                    <td id="schedule-data">{{ employee.name }}</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer"></div>
</div>



<script src="webjars/vue/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>


<script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#page-container',
        components: {
        },
        data() {
            return {
                employees: null,
                shiftsDB: null,
                postScheduleBody: '',
                solvedScheduleBody: '',
                counter: 0,
                daysOfWeek: null
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getEmployees();
            this.getDaysOfWeek();
        },
        methods: {
            getEmployees: function () {
                axios
                    .get("/api/employees")
                    .then(response => (this.employees = response.data))
            },
            getAllShifts: function() {
                axios
                    .get("/api/shifts")
                    .then(response => (this.shifts = response.data))
            },
            postToSolver: function() {
                axios.post('/api/solve', {
                    "shifts":[
                        {
                            "sid":0,
                            "startTime":"09:00",
                            "endTime":"18:00",
                            "day": "Monday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel": 12
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":1,
                            "startTime":"12:00",
                            "endTime":"20:00",
                            "day": "Monday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":2,
                            "startTime":"18:00",
                            "endTime":"00:00",
                            "day": "Monday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "sid": 3,
                            "startTime":"09:00",
                            "endTime":"18:00",
                            "day": "Tuesday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel": 12
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":4,
                            "startTime":"12:00",
                            "endTime":"20:00",
                            "day": "Tuesday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":5,
                            "startTime":"18:00",
                            "endTime":"00:00",
                            "day": "Tuesday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel":10
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":6,
                            "startTime":"09:00",
                            "endTime":"18:00",
                            "day": "Wednesday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel": 12
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":7,
                            "startTime":"12:00",
                            "endTime":"20:00",
                            "day": "Wednesday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":8,
                            "startTime":"18:00",
                            "endTime":"00:00",
                            "day": "Wednesday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel":10
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":9,
                            "startTime":"09:00",
                            "endTime":"18:00",
                            "day": "Thursday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel": 12
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":10,
                            "startTime":"12:00",
                            "endTime":"20:00",
                            "day": "Thursday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":11,
                            "startTime":"18:00",
                            "endTime":"00:00",
                            "day": "Thursday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel":10
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":12,
                            "startTime":"09:00",
                            "endTime":"18:00",
                            "day": "Friday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel": 12
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":13,
                            "startTime":"12:00",
                            "endTime":"20:00",
                            "day": "Friday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":14,
                            "startTime":"18:00",
                            "endTime":"00:00",
                            "day": "Friday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel":10
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":12,
                            "startTime":"09:00",
                            "endTime":"18:00",
                            "day": "Saturday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel": 12
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":13,
                            "startTime":"12:00",
                            "endTime":"20:00",
                            "day": "Saturday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":14,
                            "startTime":"18:00",
                            "endTime":"00:00",
                            "day": "Saturday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel":10
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":12,
                            "startTime":"09:00",
                            "endTime":"18:00",
                            "day": "Sunday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel": 12
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":13,
                            "startTime":"12:00",
                            "endTime":"20:00",
                            "day": "Sunday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel": 10
                        },
                        {
                            "sid":14,
                            "startTime":"18:00",
                            "endTime":"00:00",
                            "day": "Sunday",
                            "requiredSkillLevel":10
                        }
                    ],
                    "employees":[
                        {
                            "eid":0,
                            "name":"John",
                            "skillLevel": 10,
                            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
                        },
                        {
                            "eid":1,
                            "name":"Elaine",
                            "skillLevel": 12,
                            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"

                        },
                        {
                            "eid":2,
                            "name":"Kieran",
                            "skillLevel": 11,
                            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
                        },
                        {
                            "eid":3,
                            "name":"Amy",
                            "skillLevel": 10,
                            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
                        },
                        {
                            "eid":4,
                            "name":"Maeve",
                            "skillLevel": 9,
                            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
                        },
                        {
                            "eid":5,
                            "name":"Steve",
                            "skillLevel": 9,
                            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
                        },
                        {
                            "eid":6,
                            "name":"Tommy",
                            "skillLevel": 15,
                            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
                        },
                        {
                            "eid":7,
                            "name":"James",
                            "skillLevel": 12,
                            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
                        }
                    ]
                })
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.solvedScheduleBody = response.data;
                    }, (error) => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });

            },
            insertSolvedDataToTable: function (data) {
                let cell = document.createElement("td");
                let tbody = document.getElementById('schedule-body');
                let row = document.getElementById('schedule-body-row');
                let tdata = document.getElementById('schedule-data');
                let schData = this.solvedScheduleBody;
                let objTestData = schData.shifts[0].startTime;

                /*  these for loops traverse the schedule table
                    adding shifts where employee and day match
                 */
                var cellText;
                for (let d = 0; d < this.daysOfWeek.length; d++) {
                    for (let s = 0; s < schData.shifts.length; s++) {
                        for (let e = 0; e < this.employees.length; e++) {
                            if (schData.shifts[s].day == this.daysOfWeek[d] && schData.shifts[s].employee.name == this.employees[e].name) {
                                // let data =  "" + obj.shifts.[e].startTime + "-" + obj.shifts.[e].startTime;
                                let data = "data";
                                cellText = document.createTextNode(data);
                                cell.appendChild(cellText);
                                row.appendChild(cell);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            getDaysOfWeek: function () {
                axios
                    .get("/api/daysOfWeek")
                    .then(response => (this.daysOfWeek = response.data))
            },
        }
    })
</script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The JSON response I want to insert data from is structured as follows:

```
{
"employees": [
    {
        "eid": 0,
        "name": "john",
        "skillLevel": 10,
        "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
    },
    {
        "eid": 1,
        "name": "elaine",
        "skillLevel": 2,
        "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
    },
    {
        "eid": 2,
        "name": "kieran",
        "skillLevel": 11,
        "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
    },
    {
        "eid": 3,
        "name": "maeve",
        "skillLevel": 10,
        "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
    },
    {
        "eid": 4,
        "name": "steve",
        "skillLevel": 9,
        "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
    },
    {
        "eid": 5,
        "name": "aisling",
        "skillLevel": 9,
        "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
    },
    {
        "eid": 6,
        "name": "james",
        "skillLevel": 15,
        "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
    },
    {
        "eid": 7,
        "name": "aine",
        "skillLevel": 12,
        "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
    },
    {
        "eid": 8,
        "name": "saoirse",
        "skillLevel": 11,
        "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
    },
    {
        "eid": 9,
        "name": "mark",
        "skillLevel": 16,
        "employeeType": "PART_TIME"
    },
    {
        "eid": 10,
        "name": "luke",
        "skillLevel": 15,
        "employeeType": "PART_TIME"
    },
    {
        "eid": 11,
        "name": "jason",
        "skillLevel": 10,
        "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
    },
    {
        "eid": 12,
        "name": "tommy",
        "skillLevel": 15,
        "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
    },
    {
        "eid": 13,
        "name": "amy",
        "skillLevel": 11,
        "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
    }
],
"shifts": [
    {
        "sid": 0,
        "startTime": "09:00:00",
        "endTime": "18:00:00",
        "day": "Monday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 12,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 6,
            "name": "james",
            "skillLevel": 15,
            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 1,
        "startTime": "12:00:00",
        "endTime": "20:00:00",
        "day": "Monday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 10,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 0,
            "name": "john",
            "skillLevel": 10,
            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 2,
        "startTime": "18:00:00",
        "endTime": "00:00:00",
        "day": "Monday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 10,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 2,
            "name": "kieran",
            "skillLevel": 11,
            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 3,
        "startTime": "09:00:00",
        "endTime": "18:00:00",
        "day": "Tuesday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 12,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 7,
            "name": "aine",
            "skillLevel": 12,
            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 4,
        "startTime": "12:00:00",
        "endTime": "20:00:00",
        "day": "Tuesday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 10,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 3,
            "name": "maeve",
            "skillLevel": 10,
            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 5,
        "startTime": "18:00:00",
        "endTime": "00:00:00",
        "day": "Tuesday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 10,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 8,
            "name": "saoirse",
            "skillLevel": 11,
            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 6,
        "startTime": "09:00:00",
        "endTime": "18:00:00",
        "day": "Wednesday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 12,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 9,
            "name": "mark",
            "skillLevel": 16,
            "employeeType": "PART_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 7,
        "startTime": "12:00:00",
        "endTime": "20:00:00",
        "day": "Wednesday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 10,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 10,
            "name": "luke",
            "skillLevel": 15,
            "employeeType": "PART_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 8,
        "startTime": "18:00:00",
        "endTime": "00:00:00",
        "day": "Wednesday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 10,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 11,
            "name": "jason",
            "skillLevel": 10,
            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 9,
        "startTime": "09:00:00",
        "endTime": "18:00:00",
        "day": "Thursday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 12,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 12,
            "name": "tommy",
            "skillLevel": 15,
            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 10,
        "startTime": "12:00:00",
        "endTime": "20:00:00",
        "day": "Thursday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 10,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 13,
            "name": "amy",
            "skillLevel": 11,
            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 11,
        "startTime": "18:00:00",
        "endTime": "00:00:00",
        "day": "Thursday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 10,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 4,
            "name": "steve",
            "skillLevel": 9,
            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 12,
        "startTime": "09:00:00",
        "endTime": "18:00:00",
        "day": "Friday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 12,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 5,
            "name": "aisling",
            "skillLevel": 9,
            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 13,
        "startTime": "12:00:00",
        "endTime": "20:00:00",
        "day": "Friday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 10,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 10,
            "name": "luke",
            "skillLevel": 15,
            "employeeType": "PART_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 14,
        "startTime": "18:00:00",
        "endTime": "00:00:00",
        "day": "Friday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 10,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 9,
            "name": "mark",
            "skillLevel": 16,
            "employeeType": "PART_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 12,
        "startTime": "09:00:00",
        "endTime": "18:00:00",
        "day": "Saturday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 12,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 6,
            "name": "james",
            "skillLevel": 15,
            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 13,
        "startTime": "12:00:00",
        "endTime": "20:00:00",
        "day": "Saturday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 10,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 12,
            "name": "tommy",
            "skillLevel": 15,
            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 14,
        "startTime": "18:00:00",
        "endTime": "00:00:00",
        "day": "Saturday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 10,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 1,
            "name": "elaine",
            "skillLevel": 2,
            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 12,
        "startTime": "09:00:00",
        "endTime": "18:00:00",
        "day": "Sunday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 12,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 2,
            "name": "kieran",
            "skillLevel": 11,
            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 13,
        "startTime": "12:00:00",
        "endTime": "20:00:00",
        "day": "Sunday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 10,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 8,
            "name": "saoirse",
            "skillLevel": 11,
            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
        }
    },
    {
        "sid": 14,
        "startTime": "18:00:00",
        "endTime": "00:00:00",
        "day": "Sunday",
        "requiredSkillLevel": 10,
        "employee": {
            "eid": 13,
            "name": "amy",
            "skillLevel": 11,
            "employeeType": "FULL_TIME"
        }
    }
],
"score": "-68hard/0soft"
}
```

I want to add a data to a cell where the day and employee match the day and employee of the shift but it just adds all the data into the first cell.

Comment: Your rows have a single `<td>`; if you want more cells per row, you need to structure the data accordingly and use two nested loops or hardcode multiple `<td>`s per row.

Comment: I shouldn't need multiple ```<td>```s per row because the v-for generated the rows and the first ```<td>``` of that row being the employee name for me. I then add a ```<td>``` to a row if the employee and the day match the shifts employee and day using the insertSolvedDataToTable() function. I should be able to add a ```<td>``` to a row that is already there no ?

Comment: I just saw that you're calling `document.createElement("td");` and so on; that's not the way Vue works, at all. You're supposed to put all required HTML in the template up top, and use v-for, v-if and the rest of them to be able to render all possible data states into HTML. The key concept here is called "separation of content and presentation". 1) create the required tabular data structure based on the API result 2) write an HTML template that is capable of turning it into `<tr>`s and `<td>`s at any point.

Comment: Okay I will have to make a template and pass the json data to it so it can render the table then